BrokenPipeError when using python print with gdb
I am trying to run an application in Linux and generate the input with Python:
python3 -c 'print(".....")' | ./someapp

but getting the next error:
Exception ignored in: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode='w' encoding='utf-8'>
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

using bash ...
any suggestions?
UPDATE:
I trying to solve some pwn challenges and I read in the writeups that they are doing this without any errors.... the only change that I see is that they are using python2 and not python3....

the piped 'program' needs to read from STDIN not the 'command line parameters', below two basic examples - a script (wtf.bash) , a trivial c program (wtf.c compiled gcc -o wtf wtf.c)
try
#!/usr/bin/env bash
IFS= read -r buff
echo "$buff"

python3 -c 'print("..... b v d")' | ./wtf.bash
..... b v d



#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main ( int argc, char **argv ) {
    char in[1024];int n=0;
    while( (n = read(STDIN_FILENO, in, sizeof(in))) > 0 );

    printf("%s",in);
}

python3 -c 'print("..... b v d")' | ./wtf
..... b v d

hope this helps
